# Find server IP using Boost Asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm writing a client in C++ using Boost ASIO library. I'd like to get the string representation of server IP to be shown in my client's logs. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Any hint towards "Network Status" using boost asio is appreciated.

Comment: Identifying and reporting "Network Status" appears like a completely different question to me.

Comment: That still remains an open question here. @moooeeeep

Comment: The general rule of thumb is: one question per post.

Comment: I'll open a separate thread for it. @moooeeeep

Comment: @CMouse: StackOverflow doesn't have threaded conversations, it's a Q&A site. That's why we say one question per question. "One question per post" doesn't really make sense, posts are either questions or answers (comments like this are ephemeral - they don't even have URL's)

Comment: I'll consider it and ask the next part as separate question in the time specified by stackoverflow. meanwhile can you go through the edit and figure out the solution for the upcoming question ? @MSalters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as getting IP is concerned the socket has a function that will retrieve the remote endpoint. I'd give this chain of commands, they should retrieve the string representation of the remote end IP address:

```
asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// Do all your accepting and other stuff here.

asio::ip::tcp::endpoint remote_ep = socket.remote_endpoint();
asio::ip::address remote_ad = remote_ep.address();
std::string s = remote_ad.to_string();
```

For the connectivity perspective never seen such functionality in asio.

Comment: I am also seeking help for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(socket.remote_endpoint());
```

this should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking to do host lookup:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    char name[64], domain[64];
    if (::gethostname(name, 64))     ::perror("gethostname failed");
    if (::getdomainname(domain, 64)) ::perror("getdomainname failed");

    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    tcp::resolver res(ios);

    std::string name_s(name), domain_s(domain);

    for (auto match : boost::make_iterator_range(res.resolve({name_s+"."+domain_s, "0"}), {})) {
        std::cout << name << " -> " << match.endpoint().address() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which might print something like

```
desktop.fritz.box -> 192.168.182.20
```